# Ionic Storage v3 - Unit Tests | TypeError: _this.storage.forEach is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, angular2-testing, ionic-storage

I have a `StorageService` wrapper for `@ionic/storage-angular` where I have a function that looks roughly like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}

  async getData() {
    const data = [];
    await this.initStorage();

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.storage
        .forEach((value, key) => {
          if (key.startsWith('data-')) {
            data.push({
              key: 'someKey,
              value,
            });
          }
        })
        .then(() => resolve(data));
    });
  }

  // other functions here
}
```

I have a unit test that looks like this

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { fakeAsync, flush, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';


describe('StorageService', () => {
  let service: StorageService;
  let mockStorage: jasmine.SpyObj<Storage>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockStorage = jasmine.createSpyObj('Storage', ['get', 'set', 'remove', 'create']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: Storage, useValue: mockStorage },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(StorageService);
  });

  describe('getData()', () => {
    it('should call StorageService.initStorage()', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn<any>(service, 'initStorage').and.stub();

      service.getData();
      flush();

      expect(service['initStorage']).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
  });

  // other tests here
});
```

It fails with

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.storage.forEach is not a function
        TypeError: _this.storage.forEach is not a function
```

Storage itself is supposed to be iterable yet jasmine doesn't see it as such because of the way I mocked it, I assume.

The question is: how do I unit test this bit correctly? I don't want to create a real storage instance for testing purposes, is there a way to define this.storage as iterable via mocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions again.

My goal was to both preserve my spy object to mock `storage.get` and `storage.set` and be able to test `storage.forEach`. That doesn't seem to be possible. The answer above may suit those who only need to test `storage.forEach`.

I resorted to not using `storage.forEach` at all and instead I iterate through `storage.keys` like this:

```
async getData(): Promise<Array<{key: string, value}>> {
    await this.initStorage();

    return this.storage.keys()
      .then(keys => Promise.all(keys
        .filter(key => key.startsWith('data-'))
        .map(async key => {
          const value = await this.storage.get(key);

          return {
            key: 'someKey',
            value,
          }
        })
      ));
  }
```

This yields the same result and is much easier to test. I just needed to add the keys method to my existing spy like this:

```
mockStorage = jasmine.createSpyObj('Storage', ['get', 'set', 'remove', 'create', 'keys']);
```

and then mock the return value

```
mockStorage.keys.and.resolveTo(['different', 'storage', 'keys']);
```

It's rather straightforward from there. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Storage` is an array.

Try this for a quick unblock:

```
providers: [
        { provide: Storage, useValue: [] },
      ],
```

We are providing an empty array for `Storage` because we are doing `this.storage.forEach(`. You can modify this array to your liking.

Comment: I also need a mockStorage for testing other methods that make use of storage.get(), storage.set() and storage.create(). Would be cool if I could both spy on those methods and define the storage as an array, but I can't figure that out for now

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to do that. Check out this thread to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55813831/7365461.